# Local Network Traffic Only

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 14.04 freezes while I'm working. I reboot and when it restarts it can't reach outside the local network. i.e. I can ping another machine on the local network but can't reach site outside.

What I've tried:

- Tested other machines on the network. All devices operating normally.
- The machine in question has dual boot so booted into Windows and network functions normally.
- `ping localhost` - works as expected since I can ping other local machines.

Ideas?

Comment: Does `ping`-ing outside via IP addresses work ?

Comment: @heemayl Yes - ping outside by IP works. Awesome question. That must mean that the DNS lookup is broken. How would I diagnose and fix that?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep '^nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: @heemayl I can't put it here but it had the wrong content. Looks like the VPN software had updated it. Changing it back to what it should be resolved the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you answer with that info I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are able to `ping` beyond you LAN using IP addresses, that means it is a DNS related issue.

Also you have mentioned in the comment that the VPN software has messed up `/etc/resolv.conf` file causing this, reverting back to what it was previously (by appropriate method) should resolve the issue.